# Use feedforward to control a simple pendulum open loop system

Tags: control-engineering, nonlinear-control

I am currently simulating a simple torque controlled pendulum in simulink (friction accounted for). This and all works like a charm.

[image: Schematic of pnedulum]

Now for the control of the system am using the system's corresponding Lagrangian to compute the toruqe and feed that to the plant.
[image: Simulink system.]

My reference at this point is a sinewave with an amplitude of pi and a frequency of 0.1 rad/sec. With pi being the amplitude id expect a resulting angle with sinusoidal behavior with its peak at pi (and -pi, so a vertical position). Unfortunately the resulting plot of the reference vs the angle looks like the following;

[image: Plot of the reference/angle vs time.]

It is clear that the computed torque is not sufficient to push the pendulum all the way up to the vertical position. Increasing the frequency of the reference pushes the pendulum farther up, decreasing the amplitude to ~0.5pi eliminates the problem. So for whatever reason the feedforward is not able to compute the correct torque. My guess is that the little lag between the reference and actual position will eventually lead to the pendulum being unable to lift itself up and gradually drop as the gravitational compensation torque needed for the reference position is much lower then the one for the actual position.

Is there any way i can compensate for the lagging position and create a more stable feedforward control?

Comment: I see that you have a saturation between your feedforward controller and the pendulum. Isn't this the problem as this is likely to limit your input torque?

Comment: I have checked the saturation, it does not appear to be the problem as the maximum/minimum are far beyond the 'actual' torque at this point.

Comment: I don't think the difference between the reference and actual position causes the problem. For a better analysis you should plot the predicted torque, the required acceleration for the angle and the torques acting on the joint.